# WP8 handle exception during back navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm currently have an issue in Google Drive API which causes an exception when pressing the back button. The exception is someting like the back navigation tries to cancel an asynchronous Task, which is allready in finished state. Since I do not have the sources to fix that problem, I'm searching for a way to catch that exception, since all other functions work properly.

Can anyone give me a hint how to catch such an exception?

Comment: Show the codes in where you are getting exception.

Comment: And the innerexeption of the exeption should give us some great deal of information aswel